# What is the difference between invention and discovery?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-difference

What is the difference in meaning or connotation of 'discovery' as compared to 'invention'?  I think invention is the result of targeted search and discovery may be accidental.

One definition in The Oxford English Dictionary, edition 1971, of 'invention' is:

> "I,1. The action of coming upon or finding; the action of finding out; *discovery (whether accidental, or the result of search and effort*)".

The OED has labelled  this definition as 'obsolete and archaic'. Still, I wondered whether I might use 'discovery' in translating from Dutch to English in a text where 'invention' had already been used in abundance, just for the sake of variety.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, first of all you have to be careful as some people will use these terms interchangeably or inaccurately.

An

> Invention

Is something that someone came up with. It didn't exist before they made it. It is a result of their innovation. The combustion engine was *invented*, the earth contained no combustion engines before someone sat down and built the very first one.

Whereas a

> Discovery

Is someone finding out about something that already exists. For example, the gene that produces insulin was *discovered*. That gene has been around for millions of years, producing insulin, before someone *discovered* it.

Comment: mstorkson thank you for a polite and helpful answer.

Comment: We generally try to avoid answering blatantly off topic questions as now the OP thinks that they can get away with asking this sort of thing which means they're likely to do it again. While you're helping one person, you're damaging the site.

Comment: This is just a quick note to let you know that the question has had more detail added in case you want to update your answer.